# How to modify image name before uploading in zend framework 3

Tags: file-upload, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-framework3, zend-file

I am trying to upload image using zend form class and my current input filter is this

```
$inputFilter->add([
        "name"                                           => "ImageLogo",
        "required"                                       => false,
        "validators"                                     => [
            [
                "name"                                   => "FileMimeType",
                "options"                                => [
                    "mimeType"                           => [ "image/jpeg", "image/png" ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                "name"                                   => "FileIsImage",
            ],
        ],
        "filters"                                        => [
            [
                "name"                                   => "FileRenameUpload",
                "options"                                => [
                    "target"                             => getcwd() . "/public/uploads/logos",
                    "useUploadName"                      => true,
                    "useUploadExtension"                 => true,
                    "overwrite"                          => true,
                    "randomize"                          => true,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]);
```

It uploads perfectly, but I have some parts that I couldn't able to modify.

First, I would like `$entity`'s Id to be prepended before uploading. Something like, `$entity->getId() . $fileName` (Confusion: what if I'm adding a new entity. There won't be id)

Second, how would I get file name in controller after validating form.
This

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
 print_r($form->getData());exit();
}
```

Shows old name.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar application. Here is how I did it if it helps.

- I'm not prepending before uploading because as you mentioned the entity id remains uncertain until creation is complete.
- I'm uploading first and get the image name on server.
- I create the record in db with the tmp_name.

  ```
  // If form is submitted
  if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

      // Merge form data and file data
      $data = array_merge_recursive(
          $this->getRequest()->getPost()->toArray(),
          $this->getRequest()->getFiles()->toArray()
      );

      // Filter and verify form data
      $form->setData($data);

      // If form is valid
      if ($form->isValid()) {
          $data = $form->getData();
          $fileNameOnServer = basename($data['ImageLogo']['tmp_name']);

          // entity repository manages saving into database and return new id
          $newEntityId = $this->_entityRepository->create($data);

          // Here we know the entity ID and the file name on server
      } else {
          // Do something if form is not valid
      }
  }

  // Do something if form is not submitted (e.g. display form)
  ```

Now I have the entity id and the file name. I don't change the file name in DB (the app is happy with the server random name) but from here all the informations are available if you need.